# if a balloon full of warm air was placed in a refrigerator, what is the result?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

If a balloon full of warm air was placed in a refrigerator, What will happen to the Ballon ?

Comment: What do expect from Charles law? How is volume related to temperature?

Comment: LOL -- Not being exposed to the UV rays of the sun means that the ballon will degrade much more slowly in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The balloon will shrink and get smaller as the gas inside it gets cooler, the pressure inside the balloon falls. You might also have seen that a bottle partially filled with warm water kept in a refrigerator squeezes a bit because of the air pressure inside the bottle falls. This result directly follows from the [gas laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws).